allocate memory in a 32-bit DOS program written in assembly
Here is my 32-bit DOS program written in assembly:
; hellod.asm
.386
.model flat
.code
_start:
mov ax, 901h  ; Enable virtual interrupts.
int 31h
mov ah, 9
mov edx, offset message
int 21h
mov ax, 4c00h  ; exit(EXIT_SUCCESS).
int 21h
.const
message db 'Hello, World!', 13, 10, '$'
.stack
db 100h dup (?)
end _start

I build it like this, with OpenWatcom:
wasm -q -fo=hellod.obj hellod.asm
wlink format os2 lx op align=16 op internalrelocs op stub=dos32a.exe op quiet op noext n hellod.exe f hellod.obj 

When I run it in DOSBox, it prints Hello, World!, and exits successfully.
How do I allocate memory from this program? (Is there a good documentation for APIs and ABIs 32-bit DOS programs can use?)
I want to read, write and execute the allocated memory block in the flat memory model, i.e. without changing segment registers. I need code which does the appropriate DPMI calls for all that.
Please note that I don't want to use any libc in my program, thus using malloc() in the OpenWatcom C library won't solve my problem in this question.
I will need about 2 MiB of dynamic memory (depending on user input) in increments of 4 KiB. I don't care if this memory is in the first 1 MiB of RAM, but I want to use that as well if high memory runs out.

https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_extenders/310501.html

@ecm: Your link is only a partial answer. I've extended the question. I want to read, write and execute the allocated memory block in the flat memory model, i.e. without changing segment registers. I need code which does the appropriate DPMI calls for all that.

I don't know if 32 bit flat model runs from pure DOS, but there are 32 bit flat models for Windows 3.1, which runs on top of DOS, winmem32 and win32s which has some of the Windows NT API. Watcom C|C++ is one of the few compilers that fully supports winmem32 as a memory model, which made it popular for  a while.

The function that @ecm is referencing returns a linear address (will be same as physical if paging is off). It isn't a selector:offset. Your code should already be running with a flat model with flat descriptors in CS, DS, SS (ES is usually a scratch selector). The value returned in BX:CX can be combined into a 32-bit register with something like shl ebx, 16 mov bx, cx where EBX will contain a 32-bit linear address which can be accessed like mov byte ptr [ebx], 'Z' . To call int 31h/ax=501h asking for 2MiB you'd use something like mov ax, 501h mov bx, 20h xor cx, cx int 31h

Getting memory below 1MiB is a different call altogether (if you run out of memory above 1MiB). You'd have to use Allocate DOS Memory Block . You can call this DPMI function and request 4KiB (4096/16 paragraphs). The return value in AX is the real mode segment base, and DX is the selector (needed for freeing/resizing). You can convert AX (the segment base) to a 32-bit linear address with movzx eax, ax shl eax, 4 This is a good place for DPMI  documentation: https://www.delorie.com/djgpp/doc/dpmi/
